# Venues API - HereNow no longer passing through check-ins

Tags: foursquare

This code was working yesterday

```
var token = "<?php echo $token; ?>";
var venueId = "4bf42ccfe5eba593ba581f90";
var hereNowUrl = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/"+venueId+"/herenow?oauth_token="+token+"&limit=11&v=20121011";
$.getJSON(hereNowUrl, {format: "json"}, function(data) {
        $(".who").empty();
        $.each(data.response.hereNow.items, function(i,hereNow){
         $(".who").append('<img src="'+hereNow.user.photo+'" alt="" class="userphoto" />');
        });
    });
```

But now it is simply returning a 200 error (depreciated) and now check-in's in the hereNow item. We are authenticated as a page that manages the venue we are querying so that we see all check-ins not just friends of the authenticator, and we had this working and now we are getting no faces showing up on our board, and no results from the API.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Hi James, you can follow up with api@foursquare.com with your specific userid, venueid, and the error you are seeing to help debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got it. The way photos work changed and so you need the Prefix + the size of photo + the suffix, so this is my final code and is now working again!!!

```
function getFourSquare(){
$.getJSON(hereNowUrl, {format: "json"}, function(data) {
    $(".who").empty();
    $.each(data.response.hereNow.items, function(i,hereNow){
     $(".who").append('<img src="'+hereNow.user.photo.prefix+"100x100"+hereNow.user.photo.suffix+'" alt="" class="userphoto" />');
    });
});
```

}